# How can I make SPNEGO working with mod_auth_kerb?

Tags: apache, tomcat, single-sign-on, kerberos, gssapi

here is my problem:

**Context**: kerberos authentication for two kinds of webapps, one using Apache mod_auth_kerb and the other using SPNEGO (GSSAPI) for Tomcat. I use mod_jk for connecting Tomcat to Apache.

**Problem**: kerberos headers from client Tomcat seem to be modified by Apache, which leads to authentication failures (Mechanism level: Checksum failed).

**Question**: How can I configure/disable mod_auth_kerb (or mod_jk) for SPNEGO webapps and keep it working for the others? Is there any other solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

mod_auth_gss_krb5 might be of useful. Its available in this link http://modgssapache.sourceforge.net/